# html make image button dimensions equal to image dimensions

Tags: html, css, image

I am using an `input type = 'image'` element as an icon which toggles to pause/start a ticker. However as I am using an icon the image is much smaller than the button itself (without setting any dimensions for the button). Is there a way that the button can have dimensions equal to the image in its `src` attribute without hardcoding the width and height of the image itself? Examples I have seen simply use hardcoded widths and heights. Incidentally setting hardcoded widths and heights did not work.

Comment: Do you have some freedom with the HTML or are you forced to use a button ? Using a simple anchor tag and putting your image as content in your HTML would do the trick, with a bit of javascript to perform the submit...

Comment: thats how it should work by default

Comment: I was doing this before but I have to conform to WAG 1.1 regarding using the keyboard in the event that a mouse is unavailable. By wrapping the image in an `<a>` tag it is tabbable but the toggling doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a input of type image. i.e.

```
<input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/20x20" />
```

The size will default to the size of the image. here's a [jsbin to demo](http://jsbin.com/vowuxo/1/). It's possible you have other css effecting the button

Comment: That is correct. I had some padding on the left and right of the image in my CSS. Removing this snapped the button back to the size of the image. Thank you.